# Convert API response (object) to array in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-datatable

Trying to use mui-datatables. Have managed to use it using sample data.
Instead of my sample data values, i want to change it so that i use my response from API which is this.props.meeting.

**API response >> this.props.meetings**

```
"2021-07-06T00:00:00Z" : [ {
      "type" : "meeting",
      "name" : "Test JP morgan asia meeting",
      "agenda" : "<p>Test</p>",
      "location" : "Test",
      "startOn" : "2021-07-06T07:14:52.563Z",
      "endOn" : "2021-07-06T08:14:52.563Z",
    } ],
"2021-07-01T00:00:00Z" : [ {
      "type" : "meeting",
      "name" : "Future meeting",
      "agenda" : "<p>This is a test meeting session</p>",
      "location" : "Asia",
      "startOn" : "2021-07-01T06:13:00.000Z",
      "endOn" : "2021-07-01T06:54:00.000Z",
    } ]
```

**Full Component**

```
class Meeting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
  }


  render() {
    const {
      meetings,
    } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props.meetings);

    const columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Title', 'Location', 'Published'];
    const data = [
      ['4 Jul 2021', '12:00PM - 1:00PM', 'Lunch catch up with CEO of MS', 'Test', 'No'],
      ['4 Jul 2021', '2:00PM - 3:00PM', 'Meeting with ICBC Chairman', 'Test', 'No'],
      ['5 Jul 2021', '4:00PM - 5:00PM', 'Discussion with JP Morgan Head of APAC', 'Test', 'No'],
    ];

    const options = {
      ...
    };

    return (
      <MUIDataTable
        title="Meetings"
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}

....
```

Comment: you also need the format that we see in sample data or just convert to an array that can be parsed by mui table?

Comment: Convert to an array that can be parsed by mui table.

Comment: check my answer. i think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.
Have a look at my code.
First of all you need to create a new array which has the same length as all the meetings (with equivalent date keys).
Then you need to flatten the arrays in order to get only the values and then merge them with the date key.

```js
    let meetings = {
    "2021-07-06T00:00:00Z" : [ {
          "type" : "meeting",
          "name" : "Test JP morgan asia meeting",
          "agenda" : "<p>Test</p>",
          "location" : "Test",
          "startOn" : "2021-07-06T07:14:52.563Z",
          "endOn" : "2021-07-06T08:14:52.563Z",
        } ],
    "2021-07-01T00:00:00Z" : [ {
          "type" : "meeting",
          "name" : "Future meeting",
          "agenda" : "<p>This is a test meeting session</p>",
          "location" : "Asia",
          "startOn" : "2021-07-01T06:13:00.000Z",
          "endOn" : "2021-07-01T06:54:00.000Z",
        } , {
          "type" : "meeting2",
          "name" : "Future meeting2",
          "agenda" : "<p>This is a test meeting session</p>",
          "location" : "Asia",
          "startOn" : "2021-07-01T06:13:00.000Z",
          "endOn" : "2021-07-01T06:54:00.000Z",
        } ]
    }
    
let arr1 = []

Object.entries(meetings).forEach(ar => ar[1].forEach(ar1 => arr1.push([ ar[0], ar1 ])))

console.log('FINAL ARRAY', arr1.map(obj => [obj[0], Object.values(obj[1])].flat()))
console.log('WITH SLICE', arr1.map(obj => [obj[0], Object.values(obj[1])].flat()).map(arr => arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1)))
```

Comment: Yes this should work. Let me read through ur codes and try it out now. Thanks!

Comment: If we want to exclude a certain column, can it be done? E.g. "endOn" : , using the same method

Comment: @user8779054 i added an extra line with `slice` usage

Answer (score 0):

First, check you're this.props.meetings object it's containing the same definition which you're providing, if yes then it will render automatic and handle by the mui datatabel it self.